# Using $_GET with a submit button

Tags: php, html, html-table, http-get

I have a table with 3 columns like so in index.php:

```
ID   |   StName       |   Inspect
_________________________________
1     Wisconsin           INSPECT
2     Alabama             INSPECT 
3     Nebraska            INSPECT
```

The right most column is a submit button which takes the user to a page called inspect.php. I want to send the corresponding ID column value to inspect.php when a user clicks the INSPECT button so that I can use that value inside inspect.php, how can I do this?

Currently I have:

```
//index.php

      echo "<table border = 1>
           <tr>
                <td>ID</td>
            <td>StName</td>
               </tr>";

         // go into a loop to create more rows -- omitted
         echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $resultArr[0] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $resultArr[1] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>  <form action='inspect.php' method='get'>
                    <input type='Submit' value='Inspect'>
                    </form>
                 </td>";
            echo "</tr>";
      echo "</table>";
```

$resultArr[0] contains the ID value I want to send to inspect.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So add an input field inside the form with a name attribute which will be an index key name on `inspect.php` page

```
<form action='inspect.php' method='get'>
   <input type='hidden' name="id" value='<?php echo $resultArr[0]; ?>'>
   <input type='submit' value='Inspect'>
</form>
```

A better and simple way to go for this is without a submit, just use a hyperlink like

```
<a href="inspect.php?id=<?php echo $resultArr[0]; ?>">Inspect</a>
```

And later process this id on `inspect.php` page

Comment: Thanks so much! How would I process it inside my inspect.php page if I used the second method you mentioned? Right now I have this inside inspect.php:

$stateId = $_GET[$resultArr[0]];

But I'm not even sure what that's trying to do...

Comment: @IsaacPerez Use an `if` condition like `if(isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] != '') {/* Process Here */}`

Comment: @IsaacPerez You should accept correct answers for the questions you ask, this will help future visitors to refer

Comment: Thanks for the answer and advice. I am trying to print out the ID by using your bit of code and in the "Process Here" portion of it I try echoing my result like so:

echo $_GET['id']

But nothing happens. What's the correct way of getting the ID and storing it in a variable?

Answer (score 1):

I think I got what you wanted to work. I am using different data in the array, but you should be able to change to your needs anyway.

On `index.php`:

```
$resultArr = array("dave","fff","erere");

 echo "<table border = 1>
           <tr>
                <td>ID</td>
            <td>StName</td>
               </tr>";

         // go into a loop to create more rows -- omitted
         echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $resultArr[0] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $resultArr[1] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>  <form action='inspect.php' method='get'>
   <input type='hidden' name='id' value=' $resultArr[0] '>
   <input type='submit' name='inspect' value='Inspect'> </td>";
            echo "</tr>";
      echo "</table>";
```

And on `inspect.php`:

```
if( $_GET['inspect']){

    $name = $_GET['id'];
        echo $name;

}
```

This outputs the value of `$resultArr[0]`, which I think you wanted.